# ReactNative - XCode bug when building on real device?

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, xcode, react-native

I am currently trying to release my first React Native app and a bug has been driving me crazy for 3 weeks.

When I run my app on an IOS simulator on XCode, everything works fine.
But when I change the target device to a real IPhone (I tried with IPhone 4, 5 and 6), I have this XCode error:

[image: XCode React-Native bug]

Of course my scheme is in release mode.

I have no idea if I have forgotten something in the XCode parameters or if it is a JavaScript error. But everything seems to work well when I run the app on the simulator. (but for many React warnings...)

[image: XCode React-Native bug]

Any idea or clue ? Especially, when it says "KinderApp Release[175:60b]", do you know to which file [175:60b] it refers ?

EDIT :

Of course, I have uncommented the Option 2 in my AppDelegate.m :

[image: AppDelegate.m]

Comment: keep in mind that running on a device is not the same as using "Option #2". You may want to try first running on a device with "Option #1" enabled, and or make sure your `main.jsbundle` contains your latest JS code. It seems like you simply have a syntax error somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Option #2 out of the box is to load main.jsbundle from the build.  it seems that you've configured your app to load remote JavaScript.

The exception you're seeing may mean that Malformed JavaScript is being sent to the JSContext.

I'd start by verifying that is the case before trying to move forward.

-- Edit --

The warnings coming out of XCode do not matter at this point.

Answer (score 1):

I have just fixed the problem.
In deed it was a very basic javascript error.
I had used a basic javascript "alert" to display message to the user.
I was tolerated on the simulator.
But it crashes on a real device.
Finally I changed alert to AlertIOS.alert and everything works fine.

3 weeks for this...